# How to assign same event listener to dynamically created buttons in Vue.js and pass object's value to it as parameter?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to create buttons dynamically whose names are fetched from keys of an Object. And I need to pass the corresponding value to the method to get my code work. How do you do both of these tasks?

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <v-app-bar app dense id="abc" dark>
      <v-icon>note_add</v-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        v-for="(value, key) in button_redirect_to"
        :key="key"
        @click="render_comp()"
      >{{ key }}</v-btn>
      <v-btn depressed fab small>
        <v-icon>notifications</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      button_redirect_to: {
        Projects: "/projects",
        Requests: "/requests",
        Reports: "/reports",
        Resources: "/resources",
        temp: "/temp"
      },
      pers_actions: ["Profile", "LogOut"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    render_comp() {
      this.$router.push();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-loop, `value` is the route and `key` is the button label. Just pass the route (`value`) as an argument:

```
@click="render_comp(value)"
```

```js
methods: {
  render_comp(to) {
    this.$router.push(to);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `value` variable from the for loop (which in the first case will be "/projects") as an argument of `@click="render_comp(value)"` handler so it can be used inside the function.

```
<v-btn
    v-for="(value, key) in button_redirect_to"
    :key="key"
    @click="render_comp(value)"
>
    {{ key }}
</v-btn>
```

render_comp will then have access to it so it can be passed into this.$router.push(), making the function `this.$router.push("/projects")`.

```js
methods: {
    render_comp(value) {
        this.$router.push(value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, no problem. You're passing the `value` variable from the for loop (which in the first case will be "projects") as a parameter of your render_comp function so you can use it inside the function. 

render_comp will then have access to it so it can be passed into `this.$router.push()`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain such information - don't use the comment section for this